# How to make HTML render line breaks in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string

I am trying to build a code formatting tool. My script gets the whole body text from the server and isolates the code block. I have the code and I am trying to check if there is a semicolon symbol in the body of the text and insert a line break after that character, but the problem seems to be that HTML recognizes the `<br>` tag, so it breaks any line. I have also tried to use a StringBuilder to append that tag after the semicolon character, but it's not working.

Below is my code

```
@if(code != string.Empty) {
// Create a new instance of StringBuilder
var str = new StringBuilder();
  // Find where there is a semicolon
  foreach(var c in code) {
    str.Append(c);
    if(c == ';') {
        // Append a line break
        str.Append("<br>");
     }
  }
  // Display the code in the code div
  <p style="text-align:justify;">@str</p>
}
```

I also tried this:

```
str.AppendLine();
```

Which works when you write to the console, but the HTML does not recognize '\n' as a new line character. It does recognize `<br>` instead. How do I make this work?

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working? is the stringbuilder having what you want but your HTML is displaying "<br />"?

Comment: I think you could try `@Html.Raw(str.ToString())` or simply try `@code.Replace(";", "@<br>")`

Comment: Do you see that `<br>` in the output? Then investigate how to show "raw" html instead of the current automatically escaped version

Comment: Alternatively use <asp:Literal> in your output, it will generate whatever your feed it

Comment: @Allanckw, the code is shown and there are no line breaks after the semicolon character

Comment: @VivekNuna, Thanks for that comment. Let me try it out

Comment: @VivekNuna, I need to preserve the semicolon in the code block and just add a line break after it

Comment: @VibrantWaves then I think based on your code you could do like the `str.Append(";<br>");` or like this `@code.Replace(";", "@;<br>")` I have not tried with your code. but you need to manage the semicolon here and there.

Comment: which option worked for you?

Comment: @VivekNuna, the later one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the HTML dynamically, as in your case, you need to use the `Html.Raw()` method to render the HTML tags correctly.

You don’t need to do all this. You can simply use the Replace method. It will replace all the occurrences of semicolon with the required string.

```
@Html.Raw(@code.Replace(";", "@;<br>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option: Use [.AppendLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline) after a semicolon and wrap the code in <pre> tags.

Comment: And maybe also a `<code>` element inside the `<pre>`